# Scrolling doesn't work on IOS browsers (Safari and Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I have a mysterious `CSS` related problem with scrolling, I created a sample from my project here: [my project](https://codepen.io/Eclipse-/pen/gObGRxm).
Briefly, the problem is the scrolling does not work on `IOS` `Safari` and `Chrome`, but it works perfectly fine in Android, any ideas? I have not observed any problems in PC.
Cheers.

EDIT:
The `.contentContainer` element needs to scroll.

I have tried these:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

Still no luck.

**android(scroll working - scroll area shown with an arrow):**

[image]

**ios(scroll not working):**

[image]

Comment: As i see you have too many `overflow:hidden` properties on element is style can you explain which scroll you need on `body` or on specific `div`

Comment: @Awais sorry for the inconvenience, I need it on the `.contentContainer` `div`, so I can scroll down to other widgets.

Comment: No problem !But its already have scroll and its working as well anyway i posted and answer below please have a look and then tell me

Answer (score 1):

> I am not pretty much sure what you need, I simple allowed all scroll
>   now which one you want

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;


}


html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

  

}


/*===========main layout*/

body {
    font-family: "vazir";
    font-size: 14px;
    color: var(--color-text-primary);
    display: grid;

    background-color: var(--color-background-primary);

    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 88px) repeat(10, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 64px repeat(11, 1fr);
}

.nav {
    background-color: var(--color-background-nav);
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 13;
    -webkit-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    -moz-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
}
header.header {
    background-color: var(--color-background-section);
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 3 / 13;

    -webkit-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    -moz-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    grid-row: 2 / 13;
    grid-column: 3 / 13;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}


/*========nav styles*/

.nav {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 16px;
    color: var(--color-text-nav);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}


.nav .navigation {
    height: calc(100% - 152px);
}
.nav  header {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 136px;
    padding: 16px 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-text-inactive);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.nav .navLogo {
    background-image: var(--logo-nav);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 72px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}
.nav .logout {
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: .8em;
    background-image: var(--icon-exit);
    background-size: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    padding-right: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-border-light);
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav .navigation .navItem {
    min-height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border-light);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
.nav .navSection.title {
    background-image: var(--icon-nav-dropdown);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left 0 top 0;
}
.nav [data-collapsed='false'] .navSection.title {
    background-image: var(--icon-nav-pullup);
}
.nav .navigation .navItem[data-collapsed = true] {
    height: 48px;
}
.nav .navigation .navItem[data-collapsed = true] .navSubsection {
    display: none;
}
.nav .navigation .navItem a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 48px;
    color: var(--color-text-nav-inactive);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;

}
.nav .navigation .navItem a.active {
    color: var(--color-text-nav-active);
}
.nav .navigation .navItem a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: var(--color-text-nav-hover);
}
.nav .navigation .navItem a.navSubsection {
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}





/*============header styles*/
header.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
header.header .userInfo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
}
header.header .userName {
    line-height: 64px;
}

/*icon=================================*/
.iconContainer {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

/*=======================main section styles*/

main.main {
/*     overflow: hidden; */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.mainContainer {
    background-color: var(--color-background-section);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
/*     overflow: hidden; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    -moz-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(48px, auto) 1fr;

}
.sectionHeader {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border-heavy);
}
.sectionHeader h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.sectionHeader h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.mainContainer > .contentContainer {
    margin-top: 16px;
    height: calc(100% - 16px);
    overflow: auto;

}
.tabContent .contentContainer {
    height: 100%;
}


/*=====================widget styles*/
section.widgetGrid {
    min-width: 280px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 16px;
}
div.widget {
    position: relative;
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-size: 96px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top 16px right 16px;
    padding: 16px 128px 16px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-paragraph);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/*media queries======================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 64px repeat(10, 1fr) 64px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav {
        width: 176px;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100vh;
        right: -176px;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        transition: right var(--default-transition);

    }
    .nav.visible {
        right: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
        -moz-box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
        box-shadow: var(--main-shadow-vlues);
    }
    header.header {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        grid-row: 1 / 2;
    }

    .main {
        grid-column: 1 / 2;
        grid-row: 2 / 13;
    }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

 
    <title>پنل مدیریتی نفیس</title>
</head>
<body data-theme="light">
<header class="header">
    <section class="iconContainer">
        <div class="icon intractable hamburger"></div>
        <div class="icon intractable theme"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="userInfo">
        <div class="userName">
            <span class="userFirstName">آرش</span>
            <span class="userLastName">چایچی</span>
        </div>
        <div class="userAvatar"></div>
    </section>
</header>
<nav class="nav">
    <div class="icon intractable hideNav"></div>
    <header>
        <div class="navLogo"></div>
        <h3 class="navHeaderTitle">پنل ادمین نفیس</h3>
    </header>
    <section class="logout">
        <span>خروج از حساب کاربری</span>
    </section>
    <section class="navigation">
        
        
        
                    <div class="navItem open" data-collapsed="false">
                        <a href="#" class="navSection active" id="dashboard">داشبورد</a>
                    </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                        <div class="navItem" data-collapsed="true">
                            <a href="#" class="navSection title" id="commission">پورسانت</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="commissionCalculation">محاسبه</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="internCommissionSettings">تنظیمات آغازگر</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="voucherCommissionSettings">تنظیمات معرف</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="multiLevelCommissionSettings">تنظیمات چندسطحی</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="retailCommissionSettings">تنظیمات خرده فروشی</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="nafisCommissionSettings">تنظیمات نفیس</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="nafisNetworkerCommissionSettings">تنظیمات نفیس شبکه&zwnj;ساز</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="networkerCommissionSettings">تنظیمات شبکه&zwnj;ساز</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="supporterCommissionSettings">تنظیمات حامی</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="managersCommissionSettings">تنظیمات مدیران</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="seniorManagersCommissionSettings">تنظیمات مدیران ارشد</a>
        
                        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                        <div class="navItem" data-collapsed="true">
                            <a href="#" class="navSection title" id="orders">سفارش&zwnj;ها</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="ordersList">لیست سفارش&zwnj;ها</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="warehouseExit">خروج از انبار</a>
        
                        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                        <div class="navItem" data-collapsed="true">
                            <a href="#" class="navSection title" id="productsSection">محصولات</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="brands">برندها</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="categories">گروه&zwnj;ها</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="products">محصولات</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="productsLogs">تاریخچه&zwnj;ی محصولات</a>
        
                        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                        <div class="navItem" data-collapsed="true">
                            <a href="#" class="navSection title" id="roles">نقش&zwnj;ها</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="rolesSettings">تنظیمات</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="userRoles">کاربران</a>
        
                        </div>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
                        <div class="navItem" data-collapsed="true">
                            <a href="#" class="navSection title" id="settings">تنظیمات</a>
        
                                <a href="#" class="navSubsection" id="changePassword">تغییر کلمه&zwnj;ی عبور</a>
        
                        </div>
        
        
        
    </section>
</nav>

<main class="main">
    <section class="mainContainer">
        <header class="sectionHeader">
            <h1>داشبورد</h1>
            <h2>داشبورد</h2>
        </header>
        <section class="contentContainer">

        <section class="widgetGrid"><div class="widget sales"><span class="day">سه شنبه</span><span class="date">10</span><h2>فروش امروز</h2><span class="money">119,618,950</span></div><div class="widget invoice"><span class="day">سه شنبه</span><span class="date">10</span><h2>تعداد فاکتور امروز</h2><span class="info">297</span></div><div class="widget sales"><span class="month">دی</span><span class="year">1398</span><h2>فروش ماه</h2><span class="money">3,787,818,130</span></div><div class="widget invoice"><span class="month">دی</span><span class="year">1398</span><h2>تعداد فاکتور ماه</h2><span class="info">10,029</span></div><div class="widget sales"><span class="day">سه شنبه</span><span class="date">10</span><h2>فروش امروز</h2><span class="money">119,618,950</span></div><div class="widget invoice"><span class="day">سه شنبه</span><span class="date">10</span><h2>تعداد فاکتور امروز</h2><span class="info">297</span></div><div class="widget sales"><span class="month">دی</span><span class="year">1398</span><h2>فروش ماه</h2><span class="money">3,787,818,130</span></div><div class="widget invoice"><span class="month">دی</span><span class="year">1398</span><h2>تعداد فاکتور ماه</h2><span class="info">10,029</span></div></section></section>
    </section>
</main>
<div class="navScrim"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I have tried your solution, there are 2 problems: 1st: the who page scrolls instead of only the specified div, 2nd: the widgets below the screen are invisible after scrolling, even the first one in clipped below the screen. again, only in IOS. android is fine. I have uploaded an image to demonstrate: https://i.imgur.com/b0V47t3.jpg

Comment: @ArashChM update my fiddle the issue is with side nav

Comment: I updated the question photos to be more clear. The side nav just disappears in mobile view. Kindly please bear in mind that I only want the content inside the `.contentContainer` to scroll. The header must always be there. Interestingly, applying the scroll to body seems to enable scroll, but the header will also scroll with the element.

Comment: If i am not wrong it mean you need to fix that in mobile view only?

Comment: Okay It was so messy, I removed everything, now it's only a header and some text, no more `nav`, I still cant scroll the text in IOS.

Comment: Got it, the issue is with `display:grid;` and `overflow:hidden` on `.mainContainer` try this `.mainContainer {    display: block;}` rather then `grid` set some property like `block`

Comment: aah, it was the `.contentContainter ` height, for some reason it messed up safari scroll, i removed it and everything is ok now. Thanks for help buddy. cheers.